# Keep dropdown visible if user is on a page in that section?

Tags: javascript, navigation, accordion

I am using some basic JavaScript to hide sub-navigation by default unless the parent item is clicked. The problem is that if a link from within the sub-menu is clicked, the dropdown closes upon browser refresh. I am wondering how I could make it so that the dropdown will stay open if the page the user is on is within that dropdown.

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="page1" />Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2" />Page 2</a></li>
    <li><span>Section 1</span>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="s1page1" />Section 1 Page 1</a></span></li>
            <li><a href="s1page2" />Section 1 Page 2</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Section 2</span>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><span><a href="s2page1" />Section 2 Page 1</a></span></li>
            <li><span><a href="s2page2" />Section 2 Page 2</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page3" />Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#navigation').find('span').click(function(e){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why does the browser refresh happen? If you use an anchor you could use a function to open the menu if an anchor is present: `http://foo.com/#menu1` leads that menu1 is opened.

Comment: When they click on the LI Span it drops down the menu but then if they click one of the links within the submenu it takes them to that page and the menu is closed again. I guess refresh was the wrong word to use.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some problems with your HTML

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="page1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><span>Section 1</span>
        <ul class="subnav" style="display:none;">
            <li><a href="s1page1">Section 1 Page 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="s1page2">Section 1 Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Section 2</span>
        <ul class="subnav" style="display:none;">
            <li><a href="s2page1">Section 2 Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="s2page2">Section 2 Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page3">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also use stopPropagation to prevent any event bubbling

```
$(function(){
    $('#navigation').find('span').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I have display:none in the CSS file for the ULs and I removed those misplaced spans. I added stopPropagation but the menu still closes when navigating to one of the menu links.